# Trouble declaring Global var outside function

Tags: jquery, global, var

Try as I might I can't get my data outside the function with a global var. I have tried everything that I can think of including window.nuTime without success.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',              
    url: 'servertime.asp',
    data: {},
    success:    function (data) {
                $('#servertime').html(data);
                window.nuTime = data;
                //alert(data);
                },
    error:      function (jxhr, msg, err) {
                $('#response').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
                }
    });

alert(nuTime);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kolink is right ! You could improve this doing like that :

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',              
    url: 'servertime.asp',
    data: {},
    success:    function (data) {
                    $('#servertime').html(data);
                    alertNuTime(data);
                },
    error:      function (jxhr, msg, err) {
                    $('#response').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
                }
    });

function alertNuTime(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I admit to having a little trouble getting my brains around this one.

Answer (score 2):

When `alert(nuTime)` is called, the AJAX hasn't returned yet. Anything that depends on the result MUST be inside the success handler (or called by said handler)

EDIT: You can implement a "delay" like this:

```
function someFunctionThatDependsOnAjaxBeingDone(arg1,arg2,arg3) {
    if( typeof nuTime === "undefined") {
        var t = this, ac = arguments.callee, arg = arguments;
        setTimeout(function() {ac.apply(t,arg);},100);
    }
    else {
        // normal function stuff here
    }
}
```

However this won't work in some browsers unless you manually convert `arguments` to an array, and it also doesn't work properly with return values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I surmised as much. How would I make the var nuTime available to other functions outside the success handler?

Comment: Make sure the other functions don't run until the success handler has done so.